# Orbeon - Exposing Only the Created Forms URL

Tags: orbeon

Just want to ask your expertise regarding Orbeon, We created a form using From builder and we need to expose that publicly. So we setup our firewall to only allow the exact URL for the created form, sample below:

```
https://publicaddress/fr/ELO/ELOPreSales/new
```

However, it does not load properly, we also expose the following URLs:

```
https://publicaddress/orbeon/fr*

https://publicaddress/orbeon/xforms-server*
```

Page managed to load but some controls are not loading. When we checked using the developer tools, seems like we need to expose as well the root folder of the webapp:

```
https://publicaddress/orbeon*
```

I think this is not a best practice it anonymous uses will have access to the form builder, form runner, etc.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Exposing specific URLs via firewall

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on a firewall I would recommend that:

- If you don't need to have form builder accessible on that server at all, you can remove it entirely ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/production-war#removing-form-builder)).
- If you need to keep Form Builder on that server, but want to authenticate form authors, damn this is something that you can set up in the `form-builder-permissions.xml` ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/editing-forms)).

And feel free to post a comment if your use case doesn't correspond to the situations I described above, or that I missed anything in my response.

Comment: Hi Avernet, thank you for the suggestion. I think the article of removing some components will meet our requirements. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Perfect @xtian, and thank you for confirming this. -Alex